# Hammer on question

Tags: guitar

Whenever I try to hammer on, I not only get the pitch of the string between the bridge and the fret but also between the fret and the nut. How do I mute the high pitched tone that I get between the fret and the nut?

Acoustic guitar, btw.

Answer (score 4):

Normally that sound should not be picked up by the pickup. That being said, you should try muting it with left hand fingers "behind" the fretting finger, assuming you're not hammering on with the first finger. If you are hammering on with the first finger, I'm not sure what to do beside try to change the fingering somehow so you are hammering on with a different finger.

Answer (score 4):

Try to concentrate the “hammer energy” on the bridge-side fret. The finger should always be rather closer to that fret, not in the middle between two frets; for a hammer-on it can be a good idea to actually aim right *on top* of the fret you want, and only then pull the finger back a bit to avoid damping the note.

Answer (score 4):

This tends to happen when there is no dampening on the nut side of the fretboard; for instance, if you're hammering on from an open string. Generally speaking, when you're performing a hammer-on, the **finger on the lower fret remains pressed down while your other finger hits your target fret**.

This tends to be more common on acoustic guitars where the proper signal is not being amplified to a degree where you cannot hear the pure acoustics of the other side of the string; if you're intentionally doing a hammer-on from an open position on an acoustic as many styles often do, some players tend to mute the strings with their picking hand across the neck.

[image: Cross hand muting]

[Image from f-guitar.com]

Answer (score 2):

I have not observed this issue in my playing so I tried to replicate it on my acoustic guitar.  I found that if I let the string ring longer and snap my hammer finger down sharply, I can hear the higher pitched sound you mentioned.

But when I hammer on immediately after plucking the string, I don't need to hit the string with as much velocity to get the hammered on note to sound.

I think your best solution is going to be practicing controlling the velocity of your hammer finger.  Hammer on soon after plucking the string but with as little force and velocity as needed.  You have to hammer on quick enough to avoid muting the string, but you will find that you can add the hammer finger to the fret board with a little less velocity if you hammer on while the string is still vibrating quite a bit. You might need to pluck the string a little harder - but hammer a little softer.

Practice this and I think you will find that you are no longer hearing the higher pitched sound.  Eventually you will develop a slightly softer touch on your hammer on's and you won't have to mute strings with other fingers or your picking hand as described in some of the other answers.

Good luck.

Comment: When teaching hammer-on, I find that a lot of pupils have this misconception. They seem to think that the energy from the last note mustn't be lost in order to achieve the hammer-on.  It's entirely possible to hammer-on without a note being played previously. When the hammer is smart enough, it will sound just as good from nothing as it does from a lightning quick note after the previous one. With legato playing timing must be good, so it's often necessary to hammer-on at the correct timing, not as quickly as possible.   The velocity is dependent on the volume needed.

Comment: @Tim I agree with everything you said.  But I also know that the "smarter" (higher velocity) the hammer-on, the more likely you are to hear the higher pitched overtone generated from fret to nut portion of the string.  So in cases where the hammer-on is not timing critical or the timing works well with a quick hammer-on, the lower velocity hammer strike will minimize the sound of the undesired high note.